# df gparted space left

Tags: partition, disk-usage, storage, gparted

`df -i` report 96% left, `df` report 0% left (but 609M available), `gparted` report 18.55G left

All for the same partition

Is there any space left?

---

```bsh
df -i
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sdx0      23419200 705376 22713824    4% /home
```

```bsh
df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdx0      370150344 350620020    705948 100% /home
```

[image: gparted]

[image: gnome]

Comment: Please post the output of all the relevant commands and also it would be nice to understand where 609M is coming from.

Also mind that `df` and `df -i` report absolutely different and not really related things.

Comment: `gparted` looks at disk/partition level. `df` looks at the filesystem level. Based on the limited information available so far, I'd say that the filesystem is not the full disk/partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an `ext4` filesystem it looks good to me.

- Disk space available: 353 GiB
- Disk space used: 334.3 GiB
- Actual remaining disk space: 18.7 GiB

The `extN` filesystems reserve 5% for root access, so that when users fill up the filesystem there's still a little left for the system, and for housekeeping and filesystem maintenance.

- 5% of available disk space: 353 * 5% = 17.7 GiB
- Total effectively available disk space: 353 * 95% = 335.4 GiB
- Effectively remaining disk space: 335.4 - 334.3 = 1.1 GiB, i.e. it's near enough full

The remaining difference between my 17.7 GiB and `parted`'s 18.63 GiB is just under 1 GiB, which could conceivably be explained as filesystem overhead for the metadata (directory structures, etc.)

I would assume that the "603.5 MB free" message may creep upwards towards my theoretical 1.1 GiB a little once you've emptied the "trash" folder, but basically as far as (non-root) users are concerned the disk is full as evidenced by the `100%` shown in your output from `df`:

> ```
> Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
> /dev/sdx0      370150344 350620020    705948 100% /home
> ```

Given that this isn't the root filesystem, you might want to consider reducing the 5% reservation down to, say, 2%. Here's how I might do it for a filesystem here:

```
tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | grep -i 'block count'
Block count:              1572608
Reserved block count:     78630

awk 'BEGIN { print int( (78630 * 100) / 1572608 +.5 )  }'    # Current %
5

tune2fs -m 2 /dev/sda1    # Change reservation %
tune2fs 1.43.4 (31-Jan-2017)
Setting reserved blocks percentage to 2% (31452 blocks)
```

Confirm that we have what we expect

```
tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | grep -i 'block count'
Block count:              1572608
Reserved block count:     78630

awk 'BEGIN { print int( (31452 * 100) / 1572608 +.5 )  }'    # New %
2
```

Comment: Definitely not understanding

Comment: Okay I get it, I never heard about that. So which command is truthful about the space that I can use?

Comment: "which command is truthful about the space that I can use" as a user?

Comment: "which command is truthful about the space that I can use" as a user?

Comment: Thank you, add it to your answer and I will select it